# Joining tables and strings to Generate an order item for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a practice case and I have these tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE customer_orders (
      "order_id" INTEGER,
      "customer_id" INTEGER,
      "pizza_id" INTEGER,
      "exclusions" VARCHAR(4),
      "extras" VARCHAR(4),
      "order_time" DATETIME
    );
    INSERT INTO customer_orders
      ("order_id", "customer_id", "pizza_id", "exclusions", "extras", "order_time")
    VALUES
      ('1', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 18:05:02'),
      ('2', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 19:00:52'),
      ('3', '102', '1', '', '', '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
      ('3', '102', '2', '', NULL, '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
      ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('4', '103', '2', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('5', '104', '1', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:00:29'),
      ('6', '101', '2', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-08 21:03:13'),
      ('7', '105', '2', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:20:29'),
      ('8', '102', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-09 23:54:33'),
      ('9', '103', '1', '4', '1, 5', '2020-01-10 11:22:59'),
      ('10', '104', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-11 18:34:49'),
      ('10', '104', '1', '2, 6', '1, 4', '2020-01-11 18:34:49');
    
    
    CREATE TABLE pizza_toppings (
      "topping_id" INTEGER,
      "topping_name" VARCHAR(50)
    );
    INSERT INTO pizza_toppings
      ("topping_id", "topping_name")
    VALUES
      (1, 'Bacon'),
      (2, 'BBQ Sauce'),
      (3, 'Beef'),
      (4, 'Cheese'),
      (5, 'Chicken'),
      (6, 'Mushrooms'),
      (7, 'Onions'),
      (8, 'Pepperoni'),
      (9, 'Peppers'),
      (10, 'Salami'),
      (11, 'Tomatoes'),
      (12, 'Tomato Sauce')

CREATE TABLE pizza_names (
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,
  "pizza_name" VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO pizza_names
  ("pizza_id", "pizza_name")
VALUES
  (1, 'Meatlovers'),
  (2, 'Vegetarian');
```

And I'm asked:
Generate an order item for each record in the customers_orders table in the format of one of the following:

- Meat Lovers
- Meat Lovers - Exclude Beef
- Meat Lovers - Extra Bacon
- Meat Lovers - Exclude Cheese, Bacon - Extra Mushroom, Peppers

So far I have been able to do this:

```
--for Extras
  SELECT concat(cast(pn.pizza_name as varchar), pt.topping_name ) as pizzas_plus_extras
FROM customer_orders as co
    CROSS APPLY string_split((extras), ',') 
full JOIN pizza_toppings as pt
ON VALUE in (cast(topping_id as varchar))
INNER JOIN pizza_names AS pn
ON co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id

--for exclusions

SELECT concat(cast(pn.pizza_name as varchar), pt.topping_name ) as pizzas_plus_exclusions
FROM customer_orders as co
    CROSS APPLY string_split((exclusions), ',') 
full JOIN pizza_toppings as pt
ON VALUE in (cast(topping_id as varchar))
INNER JOIN pizza_names AS pn
ON co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
```

That gives me  these results:

[image]

For some reason it doesn't want to show ALL the records (in extras It won't name toppings number 5 and 4 and same thing with exclusions number 6), And I have  2 different tables that I dont know how to join and get the results I'm asked.

I tried `String_agg` to add a separator but I used it on each table so, as you can see I still can't get the expected result.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: a few things, fix the pizza_names table so it does not TRUNCATE data and is it ok that you have columns with comma separated values ie: exclusion has 2,6 and extras has 1,5 and 1,4 ?

Comment: btw, i would normalize that comma separated column TABLES and use a junction TABLE please tell that to who asked you to do this. maybe it was on purpose ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator hi, um one question, how can I fix the  pizza_names table? I wasn't sure what TRUNCATE means, I just read on google but...I dont know how to fix it? I haven't have problems with that table so far in the other questions of this pracite.   / And Yeah the comma separated values were a headache in other questions, thats why in my query Im using the string_split((extras), ',')  to solve that problem.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator and yeah there is a lot of "weird" things  on purpose I suppose. This is a practice case from 8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-2/ if you want to check it out in case there is something that is not clear. I noticed they do a lot of "not efficient" things to make you do it for them to learn how to do it and practice I guess

Comment: since you changed the question while i was posting the response related to EXTRAS please let me know if it is ok and i can start from there

Comment: @jmvcollaborator oh yes love that I can finally see the chicken and cheese that I wasn't able to see before! I didn't know you can do a query right after a join! or to use * for the string_split!

Comment: im updating the answer to cover all the FOUR scenarios you have.

Comment: and yes, with this practice case I'm definitely learning that having a column with comma separated ids is terrible and nothing but headaches haha

Comment: please take a look at the UPDATE section hope it works and if so appreciate if you can mark the response as the answer.

Comment: I would do two simple subqueries: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5xpRqPQW).

Comment: So I just check it out and I think either one of us is having a wrong interpretantion of the expected results. I totally see how you can read the expected results in come up with the four tables you did and looks great. But isn't the problem asking for the end result to be, for example, "Meat Lovers - Exclude Cheese, Bacon - Extra Mushroom, Peppers" all of that in one single cell? since that is one pizza. Like for pizza in order_id 7 it would be a single cell that reads "Vegetarian - Extra Bacon" What do you think? maybe my interpretation is wrong? Also english is my second language so...

Comment: no hay problema you can concatenate column values with + operator in the select statement

Comment: Oh I just got your second message haha Ill check it out rn

Comment: omg yes is perfect! Im going to sit down for hours studying it haha thank you so much! I was going insane all day with this haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string_split to join with a column with comma separated ids. **Notice: in real world this is a bad practice.**

For extras:

```
SELECT co.order_id,co.customer_id,pn.pizza_name + '-' + pt.topping_name as pizza
FROM customer_orders co
inner join pizza_names pn on co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
inner join pizza_toppings pt on pt.topping_id in  (select * from string_split(co.extras, ','))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
-- ALL Meat Lovers (NO EXTRAS NO EXCLUSIONS)
Select co.order_id,co.customer_id,pn.pizza_name
FROM customer_orders co
inner join pizza_names pn on co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
where pn.pizza_name='Meatlovers'
and 
(
 (exclusions is null or exclusions = '')
  AND
 (extras is null or extras = '')
 )

-- ALL PIZZAS (EXCLUDE BEEF)
SELECT co.order_id,co.customer_id,pn.pizza_name + '-' + pt.topping_name as pizza
FROM customer_orders co
inner join pizza_names pn on co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
inner join pizza_toppings pt on pt.topping_id in  (select * from string_split(co.exclusions, ','))
and pt.topping_name <>'Beef'

-- ALL PIZZAS (EXTRA BACON)
SELECT co.order_id,co.customer_id,pn.pizza_name + '-' + pt.topping_name as pizza
FROM customer_orders co
inner join pizza_names pn on co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
inner join pizza_toppings pt on pt.topping_id in  (select * from string_split(co.extras, ','))
and pt.topping_name= 'Bacon'

-- ALL PIZZAS (EXCLUDE CHEESE,BACON - EXTRA MUSHROOM, PEPPERS)

SELECT co.order_id,co.customer_id,pn.pizza_name + '-' + pt.topping_name as pizza
FROM customer_orders co
inner join pizza_names pn on co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
inner join pizza_toppings pt on pt.topping_id in  (select * from string_split(co.exclusions, ','))
and pt.topping_name<> 'Bacon' and pt.topping_name<> 'Cheese'
inner join pizza_toppings pt1 on pt1.topping_id in  (select * from string_split(co.extras, ','))
and pt1.topping_name='Mushrooms'or pt1.topping_name='Peppers'
```